# submitting webforms python

Tags: python, python-3.x, webforms, urllib

I am trying to submit this webform and log into this site:
https://www.kalahari.net/profile/pipeline/signin.aspx

I keep getting the login site's source code as output when the script is done,so it seems like all is working (no errors) but it's just not logging in. I can't find what I am doing wrong.Please help.
I am using Python 3.1.2, I can't use Mechanize as the code needs to be written in Python 3.x

I think my problem might be the POST url I am posting the login information to, but I cant seem to figure it out, and what it should be.

```
f=open("page_src.html",'wb') 
cj=cookiejar.CookieJar()

params=urllib.parse.urlencode({'ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtEmail': 'username', 'ctl00$ctl00$cplhMain$cplhContent$txtPassword': 'pass'})

opener = req.build_opener(req.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener()
page = opener.open("https://www.kalahari.net/profile/pipeline/signin.aspx", params)

profilepage = opener.open("https://www.kalahari.net/profile/pipeline/profile.aspx")
source=profilepage.read()

f.write(source)
f.close()
```

Comment: Try using something like tcpwatch to see what your browser sends when you log in, and what Python sends.

Comment: drop `'?'` at the end of the url

Comment: I dropped the ?.Still not working.

Comment: Use wireshark to compare what is sent when you use a browser and your script. See Referer, User-Agent,Content-Type headers, generated hidden values, requests for other files (maybe css file with a generated name), etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble using Wireshark, can anyone help with how I would go about finding the actionurl of this site I'm trying to access using Wireshark? I've installed wireshark and started an active monitor,then clicked the 'signin' button. There is a massive amount of http traffic thought and I'm not sure what I'm looking for...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is probably using cookies for the login, so you must too. That means you must save the cookies you get when you log in and send them to the site with each following request.

Check out [http.cookiejar](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.cookiejar.html).

Comment: I edited my code to use cookiejar, as far as I can tell I used it correctly? But it still doesnt log in.Any more suggestions, critique?